# How can I solve this depency error in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I can't find out, where my problem is. I get the following error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BService (?, AService). Please
>   make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the CModule
>   context.

I have 3 Modules, A, B, C.

C should be able to use services from B, and B should call services from A.

A and B have TypeOrm imports and an entity each.

Here is the code:

app.modules.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    CModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

c.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [BModule],
  controllers: [CController],
  providers: [BService]
})
export class CModule {}
```

b.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([B], 'default')
  ],
  providers: [BService],
  exports: [AModule, BService]
})
```

b.entity.ts:

```
@Entity()
export class B {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

}
```

b.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class BService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(B, 'default')
    private readonly bRepository: Repository<B>,
    private readonly aService: AService
  ) {}
}
```

a.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([A], 'default')
  ],
  providers: [AService],
  exports: [AService]
})
export class AModule {}
```

a.entity.ts:

```
@Entity()
export class A {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

a.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(A, 'default')
    private readonly aRepository: Repository<A>) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CModule` you do not need to define `providers: [BModule]` as you will overwrite the value given from `BModule`. As `BModule` already exports `BService` you shouldn't need to do anything other than import `BModule` into your `CModule` then you can use `BService` with no problems.

Side remark: is there any reason you have dependencies across your modules? Most of the time if you can keep from importing other modules if it isn't necessary it'll make a lot of your code easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you, I have overlooked this. Regarding the module dependencies: My thougt is to hold all the code with a specific concern together in a module, e.g. add handling for entity B in module B and handling for entity A in module A. The feature module C just needs Entity B, therefore it has to call B-Services, but Entity B needs Entity A for beeing constructed. Is it not best practice to do it this way?